# Can't Access class methods using Composition?

Tags: java, methods, nullpointerexception, program-entry-point, composition

In the below example I encountered  `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Brief overview:   Class STANDALONE is related to class FACULTY by composition, because STANDALONE has an instance variable that holds a reference to a FACULTY object. I am trying to utilize the use of Composition and getting the below error.  Please advice.

FYI: This is the piece of the code where I have the problem.

```
 public abstract class person { // getters setters }

 public class faculty extends person {

              public faculty(){super();}

              public void someMethod(){  //some stuff "method calls" }


}

public class standalone {

         //composition has-a relationship

          public faculty faculty;

          public void facultyInfo(){

        // Compiler is complaining about this line
                faculty.someMethod();}
}

public class MainOne {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

         standalone stand = new  standalone();

                //Compiler is complaining about this line 
                  stand.facultyInfo();
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at first_.standalone.facultyStuff(standalone.java:22)
    at first_.MainOne.main(MainOne.java:13)
```

Comment: BTW, everything else works as expected . I only had this when I added the Composition component of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means `faculty` member is `null` in your `standalone` instance.
You need to initialize it. You may want to e.g. add a constructor to `standalone` and initialize the `faculty` in there.

```
public standalone(){
    this.faculty = new faculty();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

faculty variable is not initlalized.

Comment: Actually it was initialized by default to `null`.

Comment: That is what I thought @PM 77-1  ......doing new faculty();  which allocting space and creating instance of the object did the job

Comment: @NullSoulException - If you call a `someMethod()` against the reference variable that is `null` you're guaranteed to get `NPE`.

Answer (score 2):

You declare the `faculty` variable but you never initialize it.

```
public faculty faculty;
```

After this `faculty` hasn't been explicitly initialized. Since it's an instance variable Java automatically initializes it to be `null`.

You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
public faculty faculty = new faculty();
```

Or initialize it in the constructor:

```
public class standalone {
    public faculty faculty;

    public faculty() {
        this.faculty = new faculty();  // Now faculty is initialized and useable
    }

    public void facultyInfo(){

        faculty.someMethod();}
    }
}
```